# Detect ViewPager tab change inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a `ViewPager` with multiple fragments. In one `Fragment` I play audio. When I swipe to another fragment I want to stop the audio playback. How do I detect that the another fragment is now visible in the `ViewPager`?

I've tried overriding `onStop` and `onHiddenChanged`. No success. There must be some "you're not active anymore" method to override. No?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

I did some digging and it turns out that ViewPager will call both: `setUserVisibleHint` and `setMenuVisibility`.  I would override `setUserVisibleHint` since the [documentation for setUserVisibleHint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#setUserVisibleHint%28boolean%29) states:

> Set a hint to the system about whether this fragment's UI is currently visible to the user. This hint defaults to true and is persistent across fragment instance state save and restore.
>   An app may set this to false to indicate that the fragment's UI is scrolled out of visibility or is otherwise not directly visible to the user. This may be used by the system to prioritize operations such as fragment lifecycle updates or loader ordering behavior.

Try putting this code in your fragment:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

    // Make sure that we are currently visible
    if (this.isVisible()) {
        // If we are becoming invisible, then...
        if (!isVisibleToUser) {
            Log.d("MyFragment", "Not visible anymore.  Stopping audio.");
            // TODO stop audio playback
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: setUserVisibleHint was never called in my case.

Comment: Wayne: In my experience, I've found that setUserVisibleHint is called if ViewPager's adapter is a FragmentPagerAdapter, but not if it is a FragmentStatePagerAdapter.  So if you're having issues, try to make sure you're using FragmentPagerAdapter.

Comment: Yichuan Wang: To use Fragment's setUserVisibleHint in lower API levels, use the Android Support Library http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html  For example, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#setUserVisibleHint(boolean) is available for API level 4.

Comment: Works great but this is not called again after orientation change. Therefore the hint is not restored but the fragment is. How can I achieve a recall?

Comment: Same for me: this isn't called after calling (and finishing it) a new activity from the fragment, so not valid for me

Comment: You need to handle `onResume` and `onOrientationChanged` too.

Comment: And you can use getUserVisibleHint() in your onOrientationCahnged method.

Comment: didn't work. Still gets called when I select a neighbor, and claims it's visible (as it technically is, as you can start to drag and see part of it.)

Comment: This is not reliable, it get called automatically sometimes. I found a better alternative http://stackoverflow.com/a/25822814/1979347