# Determine when a ViewPager changes pages

Tags: android, android-widget, android-viewpager

I have three pages (Fragments) inside a ViewPager, however I only want to display a menu item for two of those pages.

The code given in a [previous SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11075663/418084) does not seem to work:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

    if (isVisibleToUser == true) { }
    else if (isVisibleToUser == false) {  }

}
```

Eclipse says @Override isn't needed and super can't be set. It's never called by the system, and even if it was how would I determine which page was being shown at the moment? Could I have some help here?

Comment: This one worked for me, and gives a little more context about how to use the given solution: [Detect ViewPager tab change inside Fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779397/detect-viewpager-tab-change-inside-fragment).

Answer (score 328, accepted):

Use the `ViewPager.onPageChangeListener`:

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        // Check if this is the page you want.
    }
});
```

Comment: You can use a SimpleOnPageChangeListener instead and only override onPageSelected

Answer (score 127):

`ViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener` is deprecated now. You now need to use `ViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener` instead.

*for example,*

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: I seem not to understand. Am an absolute beginner. So what do we put inside those methods. Please help me on where to learn `addOnPageChangeListener`.

Comment: +1 for the info, but what is the difference of these two `ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener` and `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` as what mention above?

Comment: @RoCk With SimpleOnPageChangeListener you only need to override the methods you actually want to use. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/31961397/608312 for example.

Answer (score 46):

For ViewPager2,

```
viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
  override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
    super.onPageSelected(position)
  }
})
```

where `OnPageChangeCallback` is a static class with three methods:

```
onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, @Px int positionOffsetPixels),
onPageSelected(int position), 
onPageScrollStateChanged(@ScrollState int state)
```

Answer (score 40):

You can also use `ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener` instead of `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` and override only those methods you want to use.

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {

    // optional 
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) { }

    // optional 
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) { }

    // optional 
    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) { }
});
```

Hope this help :)

**Edit:**
As per android APIs, `setOnPageChangeListener (ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener listener)` is deprecated. Please check this url:- [Android ViewPager API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOnPageChangeListener(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener))

Comment: As `mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener();` is deprecated now, this one is working fine.

Comment: In the above code, to detect whether a state has changed save the current position and compare it when the page is scrolled in onPageScrolled method.

Answer (score 38):

**Kotlin Users**,

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(object : ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

            override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {
            }

            override fun onPageScrolled(position: Int, positionOffset: Float, positionOffsetPixels: Int) {

            }

            override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
            }
        })
```

**Update 2020 for ViewPager2**

```
        viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
        override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {
            println(state)
        }

        override fun onPageScrolled(
            position: Int,
            positionOffset: Float,
            positionOffsetPixels: Int
        ) {
            super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels)
            println(position)
        }


        override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
            super.onPageSelected(position)
            println(position)
        }
    })
```