# Changing or replacing fragments in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Created a class which implements `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and provided the function  `@Override public Fragment getItem(int position)` in which I'm just creating and retuning fragment instance.

Then I've two functions, which is just changing the current page in `ViewPager`.

```
public void next() {
    this.mPager.setCurrentItem(this.mPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
}

public void prev() {
    this.mPager.setCurrentItem(this.mPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
}
```

So whenever the page is getting changed, I'm not getting call inside of any life-cycle functions, so that I can take any decision when the page is becoming visible, hidden etc...

**Question**

1. How to properly implement ViewPager for Wizard things (for example registration or poll)
2. Also I've read something like code below for properly changing/replacing the fragments. But how this can be used with ViewPager?

Please let me know

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
               .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
               .commit();
```

Comment: Check this link https://dzone.com/articles/android-tutorial-using and cross check your view pager implementation

Comment: check this http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Comment: @VivekMishra I checked the link you have shared, but still my questions are unanswered there. I have the working code, but I want to get the life-cycle call on when my views are getting replaced by ViewPager and FragmentManger.

Comment: @GauravPolekar I had followed the same android tutorial which you have mentioned. But my question are after that. I will appreciate if you please read my question one more time.

Comment: if you are manually sliding pages then I think pageChangeListener  should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FragmentStatePagerAdapter by default preloads adjacent fragment to that of showing fragment.

means if fragment 0 is showing fragment 1 also gets loaded with it.
similarly if fragment 5 is showing then 4 and 6 will also be loaded with it.

hence when you slide from 4 to 5, 5's life cycle wont be called as it was already called.

you need to implement OnPageChangeListener to identify the change.

Comment: thanks for reply. Can you please tell me where to add the `OnPageChangeListener`. I guess on `ViewPager` class...???

Comment: Also when fragment 5 is shown after moving from 1 to 5, then fragments 1, 2, 3 OnDestroy() methods must be called?

Comment: how to add listener -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293300/determine-when-a-viewpager-changes-pages

Comment: and for your second question, yes 1,2,3 fragment will be destroyed if offscreen page size is set to 1. if it is set to 2 then 2 additional fragment on either side of the current fragment will be loaded. and of course this applies to FragmentStatePagerAdapter. FragmentPagerAdapter will keep all its fragments in memory

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In **onCreate()**,

```
pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
pager.setAdapter(adapter);
// Here you can specify how many pages(Fragments) to load.
pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
pager.setPageMargin(pageMargin);

// Setting PageChangeListener...        
pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position)
    {
        // Here, you have a current selected page
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state)
    {

    }
});    

// This method is used to get the current selected fragment from `ViewPager`
private YourFragment getCurrentFragment()
{
    YourFragment fragment = (YourFragment) adapter.getRegisteredFragment(pager.getCurrentItem());
    return fragment;
}
```

Now, `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` code

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{
    // Titles of the fragments
    private final String[] TITLES = { ... };
    SparseArray<Fragment> registeredFragments = new SparseArray<Fragment>();

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
    {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
    {
        return TITLES[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return TITLES.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        if (position == 0)
        {
            return Fragment1.newInstance(position);
        }
        else if (position == 1)
        {
            return Fragment2.newInstance(position);
        }
        else if (position == 2)
        {
            return Fragment3.newInstance(position);
        }
        return Fragment4.newInstance(position);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)
    {
        Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        registeredFragments.put(position, fragment);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object)
    {
        registeredFragments.remove(position);
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
    }

    public Fragment getRegisteredFragment(int position)
    {
        return registeredFragments.get(position);
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you out.