# How to pass data from one fragment to last fragment from multiple fragment?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-intent, fragment, bundle

I have nine fragment in my ViewPager and each fragment have 10 EditText. User enter value in all EditText. I have submit button on my last ninth fragment. I want to store data in Sqite and then send to server when user fill all the data then press submit button.

I want to know how can i take all EditText data from my all nine fragment to my last ninth fragment where i call my webservice and send data to server when user press submit button.

what is the best way to achieve this ?

I used Bundle to achieve this but giving error. Below is my bundle code.  I am getting error in bundle2 because i want to take data from second fragment to third fragment. Can anyone give good solution ?

Fragment First-

```
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("ConsAcNo", txtConsAcNo.getText().toString());
    bundle.putString("MeterSrMo", txtMeterSrMo.getText().toString());
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Fragment Second-

```
    // getting data from first fragment
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    String ConsAcNo= bundle.getString("ConsAcNo");
    String MeterSrMo= bundle.getString("MeterSrMo");

    //this is my second bundle to take data to third fragment.
    Bundle bundle2 = new Bundle();
    bundle2.putString("txtConsAcNo1", ConsAcNo.toString());
    bundle2.putString("txtMeterSrMo1", MeterSrMo.toString());
    bundle2.putString("txtTestNo", txtTestNo.getText().toString());
    bundle2.putString("txtAccucheckNo",txtAccucheckNo.getText().toString());
    fragment1.setArguments(bundle2);
```

Comment: May you can use ViewPager.onPageChangeListener:

Comment: Will you please provide any example ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293300/determine-when-a-viewpager-changes-pages

Comment: Thanks Rasel. This is not what i am looking. I want to take my EditText data to last fragment

Comment: I have edited my ques. Now anyone can solve ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html