# How to not start all fragments together on ViewPager when fragment A is selected

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

so i'm using ViewPager to make my app much faster , instead of using an ***activity*** for each layout.

the problem is , in activity you can write your code inside ***onCreate***
and it will only starts when you ***start the activity*** , right?

but when you go with fragments and fragmentPagerAdapter and use ViewPager for them.

all your fragments going to start their (onCreateView) together **even if your ViewPager only showing the First Fragment**!

if you are you playing a sound or animation on the start of a fragment , ***it will starts in the background*** !

here's my fragmentPagerAdapter class:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitle = new ArrayList<>();

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {

        super(fm);

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {

        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitle.add(title);
    }


}
```

and i have this (second Fragment) that i don't want it to **starts without being seleceted**!

```
public class GameFragment extends Fragment{
    private View gameLayout
    private Animation showBtn;
    private Button button;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        gameLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.game_layout, container, false);



        button = gameLayout .findViewById(R.id.button);


      // loading my anim xml file
       showBtn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),R.anim.btn_show);



       button.startAnimation(showBtn);

        loadLevel();






    return  gameLayout 
    }
```

finally this is my Activity that have ViewPager :

```
public class ControllerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public CustomPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_controller);


      viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
              PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        adapter.addFragment(new HomeFragment(),"Home");
        adapter.addFragment(new GameFragment(),"Game");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);








      viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);


    }
```

i need your help to show me my mistakes here and what is the correct way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using an [OnPageChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) in your View Pager, you can detect which fragment is currently shown in the View Pager. You'll then need to check which fragment is shown and then call a method on that fragment's class to start any sounds for example that you don't want to start until the fragment is the fragment in view.

You should use an interface for this.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293300/determine-when-a-viewpager-changes-pages) you can find an example of using an OnPageChangeListener.

[Here](https://laaptu.wordpress.com/tag/android-communication-between-fragment-and-activity/) you can find an example of Activity to Fragment communication using interfaces. This example has a lot of code that won't be relevant to your use case, but demonstrates the use of interfaces.

Comment: since i'm a beginner one more question , is it bad to write heavy code inside OnCreateView for each fragment ? like initializing things and views.? or where exactly i do it .

Comment: Initialising views inside the onCreateView is just fine, in fact, it's where they should go as this method is only called when the view is being created (funnily enough), so the views will only be created once.

Comment: clear enough! now i just have to learn how to call a method from game fragment inside : @Override
          public void onPageSelected

Comment: Have a look around online. If you get stuck, ask it as another question :)

Comment: can you please take a look at my new question? nobody cares :( https://stackoverflow.com/q/48912872/8729401

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it "Might" be to just initialize the view of the fragment in onCreateView :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_media_viewer, container, false);

        return view;
}
```

Then in the override the setUserVisibleHint() function and do the rest of the initialization there. This function is called when ever the fragment is in view.

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

// do the rest of the code here.

}
```

I haven't used setuserVisibleHint for this purpose yet. But you can try it. Let me know too.

Comment: have you tried this ? it gives me an error : Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

Comment: I haven't used setUserVisibleHint specifically for this purpose, but i will check it out and update my answer.

Comment: Hey Buddy , i tried executing some non ui functions from the same, and it worked.

Comment: @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

        if (isVisibleToUser) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "getting all accounts");
            fetchAccountsFromServer();
        }
    }

Comment: and some UI work too... that also worked :) :) I initialized the main View from onCreateView, and then rest of the things in setUserVisibleHint. worked fine. :)

Comment: can you please take a look at my new question ? nobody cares :( https://stackoverflow.com/q/48912872/8729401

Comment: sure i will do my best