# How can I attach a sound to each ViewPager image

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-viewpager, android-music-player

I am newbie. I can't find an answer. I have a ViewPager with a stack of swipeable images.

I need to make it so that when a certain picture is opened, the sound that is assigned to it is played. Tell me in which direction to look, so far I can only make the sound play when the first picture is opened, just by launching the MediaPlayer, but this is not at all what I need.

Answer (score 0):

check out [`onPageChangeListener`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293300/determine-when-a-viewpager-changes-pages) (first answer with example) or even `SimpleOnPageChangeListener` - play desired music in `onPageSelected(int position)` method