# What event is triggered when a tab fragment is selected

Tags: android, android-tabs

I'm using tab fragments in an activity and the actionbar hosts the tabs. 
What I want to do is that whenever a fragment appears (or re-appears) in the view (selected by the user), I start doing something. I cannot use `onResume` of the fragment in this case, since all tabs are never really 'paused' when the user selects another tab, so `onResume` is not called

I can use the two following events from the hosting activity, but I don't want them since I expect the fragment should know this logic on its own and do that task. Any idea? tks.

```
  @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }
```

Comment: onPuase() and onResume() method called for the Activity.you have to get Fragment by tag. on PagerAdapter class put a tag and findFragmentByTag(tagname) and trigger the event of selected Fragment.

Comment: Try setUserVisibleHint() in the fragment.  [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779397/detect-viewpager-tab-change-inside-fragment)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try setUserVisibleHint() in the fragment as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779397/detect-viewpager-tab-change-inside-fragment).  When the fragment is in the selected tab, setUserVisibleHint() will be called with true, and when the fragment is not the selected tab, setUserVisibleHint() will be called with false.  This works for me using the support library.

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

    if (isVisibleToUser)
        Log.d("MyFragment", "Fragment is visible.");
    else
        Log.d("MyFragment", "Fragment is not visible.");
}
```

Comment: Launch time all fragments are getting this callback with false value. Anyways this callback is not working with app launch time.

Comment: This is not a reliable event, its different behaviour based on OS version.  Dont use this if you need to support older versions.

Answer (score 8):

You can override `setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser)` or
   `onHiddenChanged (boolean hidden)` method.

- In case of `setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser)`,
  `isVisibleToUser=true` when fragment is visible and    `isVisibleToUser=false` when fragment is  hidden.
- In case of `onHiddenChanged (boolean hidden)`, `hidden:True` if the
  fragment is now hidden, false if it is not visible.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tested this, but I believe you can use the `onHiddenChanged` method of the Fragment

From the docs:

> Called when the hidden state (as returned by isHidden() of the fragment has changed.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onHiddenChanged%28boolean%29