# ViewPager taping selected tab, scroll up its listview

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager with 3 tabs. If a tab is selected I want the listview in that tab to scroll up after I tap the same tab in ViewPager.

Right now I have a `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` and it only fires when I select another tab and it doesnt do anything when I tap the selected tab. 

What function should I override?

Comment: so you wanna listview in your tab ?

Comment: I have a listview, I just wanna know how to trigger a click on a selected tab in ViewPager.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23970301/what-event-is-triggered-when-a-tab-fragment-is-selected

Comment: It doesnt work for me. When I change the tab and go back to the tab, it triggers that setUserVisibleHint, but if I click the selected tab, nothing happens.

Comment: I am looking for something like facebook's tabs. when you press a selected tab, it scrolls up the listview/recycleview. I am not sure what function is triggered once user presses a tab button that's selected.

Comment: Can you show click handler for the tabs? It should be in there.

Comment: I should add a specific click handler for that? Doesnt viewpager have a built in click handler?