# Don't showing new record on ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-sqlite

i have 3 class. MainActivity,OneFragment,TwoFragment, I have listview which i fill using by Sqlite on OneFragment.And I add record from TwoFragment (with CreateData function using by my SqlHelper class) but new record dont showing in the listview.

How can i solve this?

If you want to see codes i can upload.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to use RecyclerView instead of ListView (as Google says:

> The RecyclerView widget is a more advanced and flexible version of ListView.

), but Both of them you need some refresh data may be like this on your OneFragment:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    items.clear();
    items = dbHelper.getItems(); // reload the items from database
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

this question may help you with your problem [Android ListView not refreshing after notifyDataSetChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14503006/android-listview-not-refreshing-after-notifydatasetchanged)

if you do not understand send code

Comment: The above solution assumes an array and would not work if the source of the ListView was a Cursor, as Cursors do not have a `clear` method. Thus if using a cursor simply omit `items.clear()`. For cursors you can also use `adapter.swapCursor(items);` instead of  `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`. I use the latter simply because it's more descriptive.

Comment: Thank you for answers Mukhtar and MikeT .Now i do your solition ways and i can do it with swapCursor but it works when i reopen application . it dont work tab change i try onPause,onResume but results are same.

Comment: I've never used fragments as yet. However this might be of use [What event is triggered when a tab fragment is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23970301/what-event-is-triggered-when-a-tab-fragment-is-selected) or perhaps this [ViewPager call setUserVisibleHint after first Fragment is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25667657/viewpager-call-setuservisiblehint-after-first-fragment-is-loaded/25822814#25822814)