# ViewPager call setUserVisibleHint after first Fragment is loaded

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

In my application, I have a ViewPager which holds many swipeable Tabs with Fragments inside. I use the `setUserVisibleHint` method to detect when a `Fragment` comes to the screen. This works great when the user swipes between tabs but it does not work on the first load. To run the code in the method I have to swipe to left and then back to the first `Fragment` because the `setUserVisibleHint` method is called before the `onCreateView` method.

Do you have any ideas how I can run this code after the first Fragment is visible? Is there a method in the `ViewPager` or something else?

Comment: When I tried to do something similar (detect which of the fragments in the viewpager was the current visible page), I had this exact same problem. Every solution I tried was a hack and it was never quite right.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can't (and shouldn't) rely on `setUserVisibleHint` for this. Instead, you should be using a [ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) to get callbacks for when a page becomes visible. E.g.

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        // do your work
    } 
});
```

*Note*: You can use `ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener` if you don't need to listen for all callbacks.

#### Update

`setOnPageChangeListener` method is now deprecated, use `addOnPageChangeListener` instead

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        // do your work
    } 
});
```

Comment: if you want to recreate actionbar menu when fragment changed you should implement it onpagechangelistener like @paul says.

Comment: Thank you.  Sometimes onCreateView and setUserVisibleHint called out of other...  This method ensures after both have been called.

Comment: Paul : How can I get this working the first time for the first page?

Comment: use `addOnPageChangeListener` instead of `setOnPageChangeListener` http://stackoverflow.com/a/30867886/1815624

Comment: Agreed this doesn't work at all for the first page loaded

Answer (score 4):

**BELOW WORKED FOR ME**

Please create a global view like this

```
View view;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        //inflate view layout
        view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment, container, false);

        // return view
        return view;
    }
```

and use this

```
 @Override
        public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isUserVisible)
        {
            super.setUserVisibleHint(isUserVisible);
           // when fragment visible to user and view is not null then enter here.
                if (isUserVisible && view != null)
                {
                   onResume();
                }

        }
```

and In OnResume method

```
@Override
         public void onResume() { 
         super.onResume();   
            if (!getUserVisibleHint()) {
            return;
          }
      //do your stuff here
   }
```

Comment: why downvote?? if anyone find any issue with it please let me know

Comment: maybe because using global variables?

Comment: @Jose_GD what is the problem with global variables??

Comment: See this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779397/detect-viewpager-tab-change-inside-fragment#comment50489740_9779971

Answer (score 3):

You have to call manually `mViewPagerListener.onPageSelected(0);` in `onCreateView` in your root activity/fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand what you need exactly but you can detect the page of the current fragment by calling `ViewPager.getCurrentItem` that return integer.

Hope it helps.

Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Well, its workaround more, and maybe its better to setup `OnPageChangeListener`, but it works for me. The task is to determine whether the current fragment is visible at creation. You can use the menu to do this. In your fragment:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true); // set current fragment has its own options menu
    }
```

and this

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     ...

            if(isMenuVisible()) { // menu should be visible if current fragment is visible right now
                setUserVisibleHint(true); // manually set value to true
            }
     ...
    return view;
```

Maybe someone will find it usefull. This works for me.

Answer (score -6):

I check your problem，but I find out the `onCreateView` method is called before the 
`setUserVisibleHint` method

```
enter code here
```

> because the setUserVisibleHint method is called before the onCreateView method