# viewpager setonpagechangelistener deprecated

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Today I'm trying to set `ViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener` and I've found out that it's deprecated.

Comment: btw, *This method is deprecated. Use addOnPageChangeListener(OnPageChangeListener) and removeOnPageChangeListener(OnPageChangeListener) instead.*, is from the documentation

Answer (score 609, accepted):

`ViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener` is deprecated now. Need to use `ViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener` instead.

*for example,*

```
ViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

You can find this [Here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#addOnPageChangeListener(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener))

Comment: It seems Eclipse couldn't even find the method addOnPageChangeListener, may I ask what support library is this from?

Comment: I think a mention of clearOnPageChangeListeners() is worthy here, so one doesn't end up with multiple listeners when using addOnPageChangeListener().

Comment: That's confusing.  It would be nice if they kept with the same syntax and simply replaced this call or something with the updated version.

Answer (score 41):

this worked for me:

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener(){

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {       
        conterchange.setText(""+(1+position));
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 39):

Use **ViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener** instead of **ViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener**.

Answer (score 11):

Just in case someone needs the solution in **kotlin**:

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener (object: ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
        override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {
            TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        override fun onPageScrolled(position: Int, positionOffset: Float, positionOffsetPixels: Int) {
            TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
            TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

    })
```

Answer (score 8):

You can achieve via `SimpleOnPageChangeListener`
Below is the Code:

```
private Fragment page = null;
/** Defining a listener for pageChange */
        ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener pageChangeListener = new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                super.onPageSelected(position);

                page = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.pager_selectPhotos + ":" + position);

                System.out.println(page);
                switch (position) {
                case 0:

                    break;
                case 1:

                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
        };
        /** Setting the pageChange listener to the viewPager */
        _pager.setOnPageChangeListener(pageChangeListener);
```

Comment: Question was an alternative for the *deprecated* setOnPageChangeListener function.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an interface if need be;

   ```
   public interface FragmentLifecycle {
   public void onPauseFragment();
   public void onResumeFragment();
   ```

   }
2. Implement Interface in every fragment in viewpager as shown

> ```
>  public class FragmentCast extends Fragment implements FragmentLifecycle {
>   @Override
>     public void onPauseFragment() {
>         Log.i(TAG, "onPauseFragment()");
>         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onPauseFragment():" + TAG, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void onResumeFragment() {
>         Log.i(TAG, "onResumeFragment()");
>         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onResumeFragment():" + TAG, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>     }
> ```

1. List this is how u user the addOnPageListener

   enter   viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
           int currentPosition = 0;

   ```
       @Override
       public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onPageSelected(int position) {


           FragmentLifecycle   fragmentLifecycleToShow =(FragmentLifecycle) viewPager.getAdapter().instantiateItem(viewPager, viewPager.getCurrentItem());
           fragmentLifecycleToShow.onResumeFragment();

           FragmentLifecycle   fragmentLifecycleToHide =(FragmentLifecycle) viewPager.getAdapter().instantiateItem(viewPager, currentPosition);
           fragmentLifecycleToHide.onPauseFragment();

           currentPosition = position;
       }

       @Override
       public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

       }
   });
   ```
2. Implement your calls in the onPauseFragment() or onResumeFragment()

Answer (score 0):

This is the new method for navbar with viewpager It Worked for me.

```
binding.viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                super.onPageSelected(position);
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        binding.bottomNavigation.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_item_Home).setChecked(true);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        binding.bottomNavigation.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_item_Booking).setChecked(true);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        binding.bottomNavigation.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_item_Transaction).setChecked(true);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        binding.bottomNavigation.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_item_HealthyFood).setChecked(true);
                        break;
                }

            }
        });
```