# when i use setOnPageChangeListener it will show error like image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, fragment

When I use `setOnPageChangeListener` it will show an error like below:

[image]

How can I solve this error? 
Please help me! 
I am using fragment.

[image]

Comment: Post error log in question instead of in images.

Comment: there is no error in your screenshots.

Comment: text strikes shows that this method is Deprecated. NO longer in use. there is some better than this method is used now. check official documentation for further details.https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html

Answer (score 0):

`ViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener` is deprecated now. Need to use `ViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener` instead.

```
ViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

[Source Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30867886/1563038)