# Scroll to top of ViewPager tab

Tags: android

I have a ViewPager with 4 tabs. One of the tabs has a RecyclerView and I want to be able to scroll to the top of the fragment/RecylerView when I press on the the current fragments tab.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779397/detect-viewpager-tab-change-inside-fragment I believe this link will help you know when you should force the fragment to .scrollTo(0)

Comment: @ElliotM my issue is that the views I need to click on in order to scrolltotop is in my mainactivity (tablayout) , but my recyclerview is in my fragment.