# Android Fragment change the visibility to next tab

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity with 3 Fragments on a viewPager f1, f2, f3 displayed in 3 different tabs. What I would like achieve is below,

```
f3 visible -> user clicks on a button -> f2 has to be made visible
f2 visible -> user clicks on a button -> f1 has to be made visible
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

The `ViewPager` method `setCurrentItem(int)` can make it.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.SampleButton: {
            if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == 2) { // At f3
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1); // go to f2
            } else if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == 1) { // At f2
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0); // go to f1
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

If you want really check the fragment is really `visible` to user, you need to override `setUserVisibleHint` on each Fragment. For that, please read this link; https://stackoverflow.com/a/9779971

Comment: Cool. this works. Dint realise such an easy solution was possible :) thank you.