# Webviews in fragments reloading on tab revisit

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-webview, android-tabs

**I have a app with 4  bottom tabs on click on any tab a new fragment with a webview loads in. I want webviews to load just one time and on revisting same tab the webview sholud be open not reloading.. how to do it??**

**I have a app with 4  bottom tabs on click on any tab a new fragment with a webview loads in. I want webviews to load just one time and on revisting same tab the webview sholud be open not reloading.. how to do it??**

```
public class NavBarActivity extends Activity {
int flag;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.actionnav);
    flag=0;

    RadioButton radioButton;
    radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.btnAll);
    radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(btnNavBarOnCheckedChangeListener);
    radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPicture);
    radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(btnNavBarOnCheckedChangeListener);
    radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.btnVideo);
    radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(btnNavBarOnCheckedChangeListener);
    radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.btnFile);
    radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(btnNavBarOnCheckedChangeListener);
}

private CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener btnNavBarOnCheckedChangeListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            Toast.makeText(NavBarActivity.this, buttonView.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(flag==0){
                loadFragment(new HomeFragment());
                flag++;

            }
            else if(flag==1){
                loadFragment(new Bfragment());
                flag--;
            }
        }
    }
};


    private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
// create a FragmentManager
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
// create a FragmentTransaction to begin the transaction and replace the 
Fragment
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
// replace the FrameLayout with new Fragment
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit(); // save the changes
    }
}
```

And my fragments are like this

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {


    View view;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        WebView webView= view.findViewById(R.id.wv);
       if(webView!=null) {
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

  webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
            webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ONLY);

webView.loadUrl("url");

    }
  // get the reference of Button



        return view;
    }


}
```

Comment: share your code of fragment and hosted activity.

Comment: @rockhack it happens with tab check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779397/detect-viewpager-tab-change-inside-fragment) solution.it might help you.

Comment: not using viewpager

Comment: Any one to help??

Comment: @rockhack, did you solve this issue? I'm dealing with a similar problem right now and looking for solutions.